# Make it more clear that an unregistered account is linked to the browser used to create it

Tags: feature-request, unregistered-users

When an unregistered account is created when creating a post, there isn't any note that the account being created is linked to the browser being used.

On *Drupal Answers*, I noticed that in some cases a new unregistered account is created for each new post.
It could happen because the cookies on the browser have been cleared, or because a different browser/computer has been used. The person who posts as guest doesn't probably understand that, even using the same name and email previously entered, a new unregistered account is created, nor does that person know all the consequences of this.

Would not be possible to add a warning that explains that the name and the email entered in *Post as a guest* are not preserved across multiple computers/browsers?

People who use an unregistered accounts already see the following message, when their reputation reaches 100. (Highlighting is mine.)

> Have you considered [registering](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/login) **to preserve your account** and reputation **across multiple computers**?

That is the first time they are informed that, to preserve their account across multiple computers, they need to register. They should be informed earlier.

Comment: I don't see what it would hurt; no one reads text warnings anyway.

Comment: I didn't realize this.  All good reasons to create a genuine account with an OpenID.

Comment: @CodyGray if there would be not too many warnings and if there would be EULA-like "I read, understand and accept" checkbox or button - won't it help somewhat ?

Comment: @Arioch'The No it won't because nobody reads EULAs. The first thing they do is find the "I agree" checkbox and continue.

Comment: @Mystical EULA's are worded in intentionally undecipherable ways, based on fineprints and on TL;DR effect. However advertisements are not what everyone enjoys and want to read through, still they are working more or less, because they are made for easy perception.

Comment: @Arioch'The The purpose of the EULA is not informing you of everything about Stack Exchange: It doesn't explain you (for example) how voting works, or what question-banning is; it doesn't even link you to the relevant page about that. In general, relevant information should be given when strictly necessary. If I cannot vote a question, that information is given me when I watching a question I cannot vote, not in the EULA, or every time I log in.

Comment: @kiamlaluno i said EULA-like. It meant that user has to say "i do accept" and while he still can cheat that is not so easy to do as to skip adv banner (and many system notices are automatically skipped just because they could be banners, reflexes are not very picky). I agree that long-long EULA does little help. But this topic was about short and context-related notices. They CAN be read and enforced by such a checkbox. Mouse tooltips are not substitute to manual volumes, but the opposite holds too.

Comment: @Arioch'The Do you mean that, with a checkbox, people would pay more attention to the warning? If they would, I am not against adding a checkbox.

Comment: @apaderno it can also then be worded more "Feature-like". Not that SO fails to link two browsers, but that the user did demand (by checking the box) the ultra-privacy (having two browser windows totally separate) and SO just complied. Sure, it is nonsense from technical point of view, there is no enforcing the default state of afairs, but if we talk about looks and perceived picture, then it makes the difference optics. Now it was **the user** who **requested** an **added value** of having extra privacy by disconnecting the (already disconnected) browser windows and SO **provided** this bonus