# Intercept misguided "answers" and edits by users with stranded accounts

Tags: feature-request, unregistered-users

In lieu of [requiring registration for all users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243712/post-as-guest-is-a-bad-user-experience-and-encourages-low-quality-contribution), I think we could do better with detecting when a user has created multiple accounts and intercepting them before it creates a problem. Most of the problems I see with stranded accounts occur as follows:

1. Unregistered user asks a question
2. Question receives some suggestions
3. User tries some solution, and it doesn't work
4. User returns to the question, having lost their account cookie.
5. User doesn't understand how to edit, and doesn't see any comment links because they are no longer logged in to the account that asked the question.
6. User posts an "answer" saying that the solution didn't work and asking for further help. `GOTO 2`.

Normally, when you go to answer your own question, you get a warning suggesting that you may want to comment or edit instead:

[image: Self answer confirmation]

However, if you're posting from a "new" unregistered account to a question you posted from a previous unregistered account, you don't get this warning! Then, you end up with two accounts, and your clarification is an answer which is likely to get deleted, so you return to your question to find your clarification has been deleted and everybody's saying something about how your accounts are messed up and oh my!!

I think there's a fairly simple solution. If the following conditions are met:

- A user attempts to post an answer to *or* edit a question from an unregistered account
- The account attempting to post an answer is newer than the owner of the question
- Both accounts have the same email address and IP address

...then display a similar notice, prompting them to recover their abandoned account, merge the two, and then post a comment or edit, or post a self-answer if necessary but from the correct account so that they may accept it.

Comment: I agree--definitely a step in the right direction. Although it's worth noting that this doesn't resolve the classic issue of that edit going into the suggested edit queue, then that edit getting rejected (for good reason, arguably) and bringing us back to the beginning. But that's also something of a different issue.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen if you detect the suggested edit before it gets made, and display a similar notice, e.g. "if you recover your account you can just edit this freely" then I think it would help with that too.